# Find every 'first field in a combination of 3 fields' in a row and skip the first field

Tags: c#, find, pseudocode

How can I find every '**first field in a combination of 3 fields**' in a row while skipping the first field of the row.

Assume we have a row like this:

> "Zero", **"One", "Two", "Three", "One", "Two", "Three", "One", "Two",
>   "Three"**

I want to make a loop and then only do something when the value is **"One"** in this case,  however the values differ from each other of course.

Note that I have to skip **"Zero"**

I need it in C# but other language or Pseudo code is OK as well

*Please let me note that I can do it with 2 loops, but I don't think that is the most efficient way.*

Comment: in this case a datarow with cells, but an object in a list or an array is also fine, I just need the pseudocode to do this

Comment: can you provide more examples ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is a `DataTable` and you want to skip the first column and take every third column:

```
List<DataColumn> myColumns = table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
    .Skip(1)
    .Select((col, index) => new { col, index})
    .GroupBy(x => x.index / 3)
    .Select(xg => xg.Select(x => x.col).First())
    .ToList();
```

This uses the integer division "trick" to get a group of three rows. Then i take the first row of each group.

```
foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        Console.WriteLine("Every third field after the second: "
            + string.Join(",", myColumns.Select(c => row[c])));
```

Answer (score 0):

use the modulo operator.

Pesudocode:

```
for (int i = 1; i < row.length; i++)
{
    if (i+2 % 3 == 0) doSomething();
}
```